# What is the difference between json-ld @id and @type in the @context?

Tags: json-ld

I copy here a part of an example from the [json-ld standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/json-ld/):

```json
{
  "@context": {
    "foaf": "http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/",
    "picture": { "@id": "foaf:depiction", "@type": "@id" }
  },
  "picture": "http://twitter.com/account/profile_image/markuslanthaler"
}
```

I don't get it, why we should use the `@id` in the `@context`. It should be:

```json
{
  "@context": {
    "foaf": "http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/",
    "picture": {
      "@type": [ "@id", "foaf:depiction" ]
    }
  },
  "picture": "http://twitter.com/account/profile_image/markuslanthaler"
}
```

Do you have any explanation?

#### A few years later

I guess the upper means the following in a more reusable form:

```json
{
  "http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/depiction": "http://twitter.com/account/profile_image/markuslanthaler"
}
```

It is a lot easier to understand if we check the flattened form first and try to compact it gradually. So the `@id` is the IRI of the property and the `@type` is the type of the value, which is here `@id`, which can be confusing, but it just means that we are expecting an IRI as value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**`@id`** tells the JSON-LD processor how to expand the term. It can be omitted if you use `@vocab`, or the term is in the form of a compact IRI.

**`@type`** tells the processor how to handle plain-string values of that term used within the body if a JSON-LD document. It can be something like an [XSD data type](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/), `@id` or `@vocab`. The last two are very similar, except one is evaluated against the document base and the other as a vocabulary term.

If the value of a term definition in the context is a string, rather than an object, it's a short-hand for specifying an object with just `@id`. Don't think of the context as an [RDFS](https://www.w3.org/2001/sw/wiki/RDFS)/[OWL](https://www.w3.org/OWL/) vocabulary, but as a kind of prefix mechanism.

Comment: Okay, I understand now, so the `@id` is the property IRI, and the `@type` is the value type IRI. I still don't know what should I define by the property IRI, but that's okay, I'll read more...